# What is the most accurate and efficient method of finding an inverse of a hessian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, convex-optimization, matrix-inverse

For any hessian matrix, of say 300 by 300, and may or may not necessarily be positive semi-definite, thus algorithms such as Cholesky decomposition may not be used.

I've found that some algorithms are not very accurate enough, and sometimes accuracy is traded with efficiency either.

For non-sparse Hessian matrix, what would be the best algorithm for computing an inverse? (the specific application of it is for online newton step)

Comment: Why do you need to compute the Hessian? It is rare that you really need such computations. Usually you just have to solve $Hx=y$ which can be done much more efficiently than by inverting $H$ (unless you have to solve $Hx=y$ a LOT of times and $H$ is *fixed*).

Comment: @MikeChen: Why is it important that your matrix is a Hessian? It seems to me that you are interested in inverting a symmetric matrix, and this is a classical problem with well-known answers. Why do you think that your question is of research level?

Comment: @AlexM. The question you ask is precisely what motivated my comment. My guess is that Op wants to implement Newton's method and is willing to invert the Hessian at each step which is not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

This would probably get better answers on [scicomp.se]. Anyway:

If you value accuracy over efficiency, using a QR factorization gives a backward stable algorithm, i.e., it guarantees that your solution is "as accurate as possible" (by the condition number bound) up to a moderate constant --- at the cost of making 4x more operations than the competing algorithms.

If you want a good compromise, the standard algorithm is LDL^T with Bunch-Kaufman pivoting. See Section 4.4 of Golub-Van Loan, *Matrix Computations*, 4th edition, for this algorithm --- though in most practical cases you would not implement these algorithms from scratch but rather use the implementations already available in your programming language of choice.